# Not able to launch any use case using Optaplanner quickstart

Tags: optaplanner

I have the required prerequisites and am able to open the OptaPlanner Quickstart in local host. but when I click Launch on any specific use case, it keeps loading and show option never shows.[I have attached an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKQTF.png).Please help me solve this.

I downloaded the OptaPlanner 8.36.0.Final file from OptaPlanner website and extracted the zipped file. Then I ran the runQuickstarts.bat file since I am using windows.

I was expecting the quickstarts to work fine but they are stuck on Loading. [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs6w1.png)

Comment: Please provide additional information. What Java version are you using? Was anything written in the console?

Comment: thanks for the reply.  java version "11.0.16" and I have updated my post with the image of the command prompt output.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by CORS blocking the ping request on the quickstart picker webpage (the application was launched successfully, but blocks requests from other webpages). I have created a PR that fixes this issue (and will eventually be merged into development and stable): https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/pull/553